Is your instrument rating tied to category and class?
Reading through 14 CFR Part 61, the Instrument Rating Airplane ACS, and pilot forums, I seem to get conflicting answers to this question.
In the Instrument ACS, it says, "if an applicant holds both single-engine and multiengine class ratings on a pilot certificate and takes the practical test in a single-engine airplane, the certificate issued must bear the limitation 'multiengine limited to VFR only'".
Let's say I have a private ASEL with instrument and I go to get my ASES add on. Do instrument privileges transfer to when I'm flying a seaplane?

Yes.  If you take an ASES addon, you will have instrument privileges for that class aircraft.
The instrument rating is for INSTRUMENT AIRPLANE which is category specific and not class specific.
The reason why there is a MULTIENGINE LIMITED TO VFR ONLY limitation is due to the applicant not showing the examiner they are proficient in multi-engine one engine inoperative operations and approach.  The instrument ACS lists the required tasks needed on a multi-engine addon with instrument privileges.

AOO VII, Task B: OEI during Straight and Level Flight and Turns
AOO VII, Task C: Instrument Approach and Landing with an Inoperative Engine

There are two ways to get the VFR ONLY limitation on AMEL.

Pilot has ASEL and IA but does not complete the two above tasks during the AMEL practical test.
Pilot has both ASEL and AMEL and takes IA practical test in single engine airplane.


So why am I limited to  private & VFR-only for SEL? All my checkrides (and Military Equivalence) for everything after high school flying when I got my Private have been in MEL aircraft, but what SEL-flavor tasks are there that don't get checked during the ride in a multi?  By the logic in this answer, shouldn't my instrument rating apply to my SEL also?

@RalphJ I've never seen a limitation of "SINGLE ENGINE LIMITED TO VFR ONLY" on a certificate.  Do you have one?  I'd love to see it.  All instrument ACS tasks can be performed in a multiengine airplane.  If you pass in a multi, you get privileges for your single aircraft too.  This isn't true for the private or commercial ACS.  There are specific tasks there that must be done in either a single or multi-engine airplane.
